# How to measure the length of a string before a specific character

Tags: python, datetime-format, string-parsing

I'm calling an [API](https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=14.5958&lng=120.9772&date=today) which gives me the sunrise time of specific cities I request.

The issue is that when the sunrise is before 10 am I get it in the format, for example, `'9:10 am'`. This messes up my code and I need it in the format `'09:10 am'`. I'm using UTC time depending on the location which is why it can give me time in am or pm.

Is there a way to know the length of a string before a specific character, in this case `':'`?

Example string

```
{"results":{"sunrise":"9:28:40 PM","sunset":"10:16:12 AM","solar_noon":"3:52:26 AM","day_length":"12:47:32","civil_twilight_begin":"9:05:59 PM","civil_twilight_end":"10:38:53 AM","nautical_twilight_begin":"8:39:14 PM","nautical_twilight_end":"11:05:38 AM","astronomical_twilight_begin":"8:12:02 PM","astronomical_twilight_end":"11:32:50 AM"},"status":"OK"}
```

Comment: What code are you using to parse this string?  An easier solution might be to use `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.

Comment: Here is an example https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=14.5958&lng=120.9772&date=today

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
import json

file = open('time.json', 'r')
data = json.loads(file.read())
file.close()

sunrise = data['results']['sunrise']
### This is the part that measures the length before ':'
length = sunrise.find(':')

print(length)
```

Comment: Heads up, the question has been edited with additional info.

Comment: I don't think it's gonna make a difference, but I'll edit it anyway.